# Butterworth filter applied on a column of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a dataframe like this (just much bigger, with smaller step of x):

```
      x   val1   val2   val3
0    0.0  10.0   NaN    NaN
1    0.5  10.5   NaN    NaN
2    1.0  11.0   NaN    NaN
3    1.5  11.5   NaN  11.60
4    2.0  12.0   NaN  12.08
5    2.5  12.5  12.2  12.56
6    3.0  13.0  19.8  13.04
7    3.5  13.5  13.3  13.52
8    4.0  14.0  19.8  14.00
9    4.5  14.5  14.4  14.48
10   5.0   NaN  19.8  14.96
11   5.5  15.5  15.5  15.44
12   6.0  16.0  19.8  15.92
13   6.5  16.5  16.6  16.40
14   7.0  17.0  19.8  18.00
15   7.5  17.5  17.7    NaN
16   8.0  18.0  19.8    NaN
17   8.5  18.5  18.8    NaN
18   9.0  19.0  19.8    NaN
19   9.5  19.5  19.9    NaN
20  10.0  20.0  19.8    NaN
```

My original issue was calculating derivatives for each of the columns and it was resolved in this question: [How to get indexes of values in a Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38580073/how-to-get-indexes-of-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe/38580158?noredirect=1#comment64575213_38580158) 
The solution posted by Alexander was with my previous code as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('H:/DocumentsRedir/pokus/dataframe.csv', delimiter=',')

vals = list(df.columns.values)[1:]    
dVal = df.iloc[:, 1:].diff()  # `x` is in column 0.
dX = df['x'].diff()

dVal.apply(lambda series: series / dX)
```

However, I need to do some smoothing (let's say to 2 m here, from the original 0.5 m spacing of x), because the values of the derivatives just get crazy at the fine scale. 
I have tried the **scipy** function **filtfilt** and **butter** (I want to use the butterworth filter, which is a common practice in my discipline), but probably I am not using them correctly. UPDATE: Also tried savgol_filter.

**How should I implement these functions in this code?**

(This is how I modified the code:

```
step = 0.5
relevant_scale = 2
order_butterworth = 4
b, a = butter(order_butterworth, step/relevant_scale, btype='low', analog=False)
smoothed=filtfilt(b,a,data.iloc[:, 1:]) # the first column is x
dVal = smoothed.diff()  
dz = data['Depth'].diff()
derivative = (dVal.apply(lambda series: series / dz))*1000
```

But my resulting smoothed was an array of NaNs and got an error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'diff'`)

This problem was solved by the answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/38691551/5553319 and the code really works on continuous data. However, what happens with the hardly noticeable change which I made in the source data? (A NaN value in the middle.)
[image]

So how can we make this solution stable even in the case we miss a datapoint in an otherwise continuous array of data?
Ok, also answered in the comments. Such missing datapoints need to be interpolated.

Comment: could you post desired data set?

Comment: I can't, sorry. If the example that I provided isn't clear enough, I am happy to modify it (if suggested how).

Comment: Did you try anything? smoothing is pretty vague, what kernel would you like? flat, gaussian,...? how big the kernel (4?)?, repeat values? how do you want to deal with the tails of the vector? Have you looked at convolve functions? Extra points for savitzky-golay method... Basically you should help us help you by trying to help yourself and failing, this way we can see how you're thinking of solving the problem and we can best help. SO shouldn't be the first place one comes to solve a problem, that's what brains and google are for...

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what I am trying to do (if I didn't fail, I wouldn't be asking in the first place, that's why I said that I must be using the filtfilt function wrongly).

Comment: It's better to ask a new question than to keep moving the goal posts on an existing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing is because you are trying to call the method `.diff()` on the result of `filtfilt`, which is a numpy array which doesn't have that method. If you really want to use a first order difference, you can just use `np.gradient(smoothed)`

Now, it appears that your real goal is to obtain a lag-free estimate of the derivative of a noisy signal. I would recommend that you rather use something like the [Savitzky Golay filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html) which will allow you to get the derivative estimate in one application of the filter. You can see an example of derivative estimation on a noisy signal [here](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/alchemyst/chemengcookbook/blob/master/Common%20problems%20solved%20in%20Python.ipynb#Given-noisy-data)

You will also need to accomodate the `NaN`s in your data. Here is how I would do it with your data:

```
import scipy.signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Intelligent use of the index allows us to keep track of the x for the data.
df = df.set_index('x')
dx = df.index[1]

for col in df:
    # Get rid of nans
    # NOTE: If you have nans in between your data points, this does the wrong thing, 
    # but for the data you show for contiguous data this is fine.
    nonans = df[col].dropna()
    smoothed = scipy.signal.savgol_filter(nonans, 5, 2, deriv=1, delta=dx)
    plt.plot(nonans.index, smoothed, label=col)
plt.legend()
```

This results in the following figure:

[image: Sample plot]

Comment: Thanks, this filter seems to be exactly the right thing! However, I still don't know how to implement it. When I'm trying to use it in the code above like this `dVal = savgol_filter(df.iloc[:, 1:], 5,3,deriv=1,delta=dx,axis=1)` , I get `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` . I also tried working outside pandas with each column (only not NaN values) as list and doing it in a loop, but getting the same result for all the values (so obviously wrong). What is the correct way to implement this filter in my code? Thanks!

Comment: Plus are there some hints (other than trial and error) or rules on how to select the best window size and degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @durbachit I've added an example which handles your `NaN`s correctly. I like using relatively low-order polynomials with window lengths chosen to include some curvature, but enough points to get the noise out.

Comment: perfect, this seems to be working, thank you! I will just have to play with it to understand what numbers will work best for me.

Comment: Finally just 3 stupid questions: 1) polyorder - what best fits data, but better not go to too high orders. I get this. 2) window length - what exactly does this mean? (documentation and wikipedia is rather confusing - Appendix in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter - in the example we are using window size 5, but based on these tables the largest to use is 4. Although without reading this I would have thought it is a number of samples over which I want to do the smoothing.) And delta - is it the sampling step in the data or the desired one in the result? Thanks.

Comment: Window length is the number of coefficients in the filter, in other words the number of samples which are used to calculate the result at each point. For a sample time of 0.5 a window length of 5 covers 2.5 seconds. In the tables on Wikipedia, the degree is in the rows and the window length is in the columns. Delta is the sampling step in the data to be able to calculate the correct magnitude of the derivative. If you have NaNs you need to interpolate them, since the filtering approach only works with constant sample length. I suggest asking a new question on that.